# Why is the ng-repeat directive failing to populate list items on a bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to do something very simple here:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Player
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul ng-repeat="name in Ids" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#/{{name.Player_Id}}">
              {{name.Player_First_Name}} {{name.Player_Last_Name}}
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can't see why this isn't working: if I attempt to simply render an unordered list then the data is displayed correctly. But as soon as I try to include it in bootstrap's dropdown menu, the button is displayed but not expanded when clicked.

Comment: I didnt like using the regular bootstrap dropdown. I ended up using https://github.com/lordfriend/nya-bootstrap-select

Comment: You'd generally want to run a repeat on the `<li>` not the `<ul>`

Comment: Try a native AngularJS implementation of the Bootstrap jQuery plugins.  UI [Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing ng-repeat on the ul element, it should be li element, otherwise you're creating multiple lists.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Player
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="name in Ids">
          <a href="#/{{name.Player_Id}}">
              {{name.Player_First_Name}} {{name.Player_Last_Name}}
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle, I don't know how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says to repeat the `<ul>` element, but don't you want to repeat the `<li>` elements? This should work:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li ng-repeat"name in IDs">
      <a href="#/{{name.Player_Id}}">
          {{name.Player_First_Name}} {{name.Player_Last_Name}}
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you still have problems, I'd suggest you confirm your module is using the `ui.bootstrap` components.  There are working examples of the dropdowns doing exactly what you want [here on the documentation page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).